# How to pass a function func as argument to another and then assignate this argument to a delegate variable?

Tags: c#

How can I use function as parameter of another function and assign it to a delegate

```
public class myClass
{
    public delegate void myDelegate(double x, string s);
    //declaration of   delegate
    public void func(double x, string s)
    {
      dosomethings...
    }
    // what is the declaration of the argument 'Function declaration'
    public void myFunction('Function declaration' function)
    { 
      myDelegate deFunc;
      deFunc = function;
    }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myFunction(func);
    }
}
```

Comment: or `myFunction(myDelegate @delegate)`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett https://dotnetfiddle.net/bNAElH

Comment: @Toshi Derp. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main is static so another method should be static too in this case. For example:

```
    public delegate void myDelegate(double x, string s);
    //declaration of   delegate
    public static void func(double x, string s)
    {
        //dosomethings...
    }
    // what is the declaration of the argument 'Function declaration'
    public static void myFunction(myDelegate function)
    {
        myDelegate deFunc;
        deFunc = function;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myFunction(func);
    }
```

Comment: Ok it work. Thinks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the definition you allready provided in your class:

```
public void myFunction(myDelegate del)
{ ... }
```

or the [`Action`-delegate introduces in .NET 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549311(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a shortcut for a delegate returning nothing (`void`):

```
public void myFunction(Action<double, string> del)
```

In the latter case also `deFunc` within your method should be of type `Action<double, string>` as you can´t cast that to `myDelegate`.

Be aware that `delegate` is a reserved keyword, so you should name your parameter within the methods signature different, e.g. `del` or just `func` or `@delegate` with the verbatim `@` in front

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bNAElH are you sure `Action<double, string>` will compile?